# C# find biggest number

Tags: c#, numbers

It's the first time I am using c# so I am not very familiar with it. I would like to create a simple program to find the biggest number if I have the user entering 3 numbers. I just need to know what to put in the code, because I am not very sure.

Comment: "I just need to know what to put in the code" lol

Comment: Check this > [C# program to find the largest of five number using else if](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/04/c-program-to-find-biggest-number-of.html)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `Math.Max`:

```
int x = 3, y = 4, z = 5;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Max(Math.Max(x, y), z));
```

Comment: what if i want to use it as windows application

Comment: @Oliver: Just assign the result to a control property or variable instead of printing it to the console: `TextBox1.Text = Math.Max(Math.Max(x, y), z).ToString();`

Comment: Then you don't use `Console.WriteLine` but assign it to the text of a label.

Comment: or write to Visual Studio's output window using debug.Write or trace.Write

Comment: What about if I want to return not the maximum value, but the field which has the maximum value? So I could return "z" instead of "5".

Comment: That is an entirely different cup of tea, @AaronFranke, so you would probably want to post that as a separate question to get good input.

Answer (score 28):

There is the Linq [`Max()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx) extension method. It's available for all common number types(int, double, ...). And since it works on any class that implements `IEnumerable<T>` it works on all common containers such as arrays `T[]`, `List<T>`,...

To use it you need to have `using System.Linq` in the beginning of your C# file, and need to reference the `System.Core` assembly. Both are done by default on new projects(C# 3 or later)

```
int[] numbers=new int[]{1,3,2};
int maximumNumber=numbers.Max();
```

You can also use `Math.Max(a,b)` which works only on two numbers. Or write a method yourself. That's not hard either.

Comment: Max extension method is in the System.Linq assembly.

Comment: @Jorge no it's not. It's in the `System.Linq` namespace but in the `System.Core` assembly

Comment: System.Core is the assembly, the namespace is System.Linq. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292667.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`Math.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/se99z7c9.aspx) method to return the maximum of two numbers, e.g. for `int`:

`int maximum = Math.Max(number1, Math.Max(number2, number3))`

There ist also the [`Max()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx) method from LINQ which you can use on any `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 6):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = { 3, 9, 5 };
        int biggestNumber = numbers.Max();
        Console.WriteLine(biggestNumber);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I needed to find a way to do this too, using numbers from different places and not in a collection.  I was sure there was a method to do this in c#...though by the looks of it I'm muddling my languages...

Anyway, I ended up writing a couple of generic methods to do it...

```
    static T Max<T>(params T[] numberItems)
    {
        return numberItems.Max();
    }

    static T Min<T>(params T[] numberItems)
    {
        return numberItems.Min();
    }
```

...call them this way...

```
    int intTest = Max(1, 2, 3, 4);
    float floatTest = Min(0f, 255.3f, 12f, -1.2f);
```

Answer (score 3):

If your numbers are a, b and c then:

```
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;

    int d =  a > b ? a : b;
    return c > d ? c : d;
```

This could turn into one of those "how many different ways can we do this" type questions!

Comment: A bit hard to read. You might move the expression `a > b ? a : b` into a helper method. In real code you'd of course use the built in methods, but it's still educational for a beginner to see how to implement `Math.Max` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple logic to find Biggest/Largest Number

Input : 11, 33, 1111, 4, 0    Output : 1111

```
namespace PurushLogics
{
    class Purush_BiggestNumber
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int count = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Total Number of Integers\n");
            count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] numbers = new int[count];

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers"); // Input 44, 55, 111, 2 Output = "111"
            for (int temp = 0; temp < count; temp++)
            {
                numbers[temp] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            int largest = numbers[0];
            for (int big = 1; big < numbers.Length; big++)
            {
                if (largest < numbers[big])
                {
                    largest = numbers[big];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(largest);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```