# Math.Max Method C# Object

Tags: c#, max, minimum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# find biggest number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117251/c-sharp-find-biggest-number)

Determining the largest and smallest numbers from user input.

```
Console.WriteLine ("For the Numbers " + (firstNo) + "," + (secondNo) + "," + (thirdNo));
Console.WriteLine("Largest is ") ;
Console.WriteLine("Smallest is ");
```

I have difficulty using the Math.Max method in this context.

Comment: Um... So, what exactly is the problem? Are you getting errors or what?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is unclear for you? Doesn't Math.Max(firstNo, Math.Max(secondNo, thirdNo)) work for you?

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to use Linq `Max` and `Min` methods to get:

```
var list = new[] {firstNo, secondNo, thirdNo };
var max = list.Max();
var min = list.Min();
```

Or in short:

```
var max = (new[] {firstNo, secondNo, thirdNo}).Max();
var min = (new[] {firstNo, secondNo, thirdNo}).Min();
```

Comment: Altough it doesn't use the mentioned Math.Max method, I think this is the prettiest solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the max value of the first two numbers and then check it against the value of the third value:

```
var max = Math.Max(Math.Max(firstNo, secondNo), thirdNo));
```

Same can be applied for min value.

Comment: +1 since it had a homework tag

Answer (score 1):

[Math.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max.aspx) only compares two numbers. If you want to sort a list of numbers, put them in a List and use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) or [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx). For example:

```
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    numbers.Add(1);
    numbers.Add(5);
    numbers.Add(7);
    numbers.Add(13);
    numbers.Add(4);
    // And so on
    Console.Write("Numbers in increasing order: ");
    foreach (int number in numbers.OrderBy(x => x))
    {
        Console.Write(number + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```

The result is `Numbers in increasing order: 1 4 5 7 13`