# Determine the name of a variable with the maximum value

Tags: c#, .net, max

I have 3 values stored in the variables `v`, `p`, and `k`. I want to find the greatest among them. The values of the variables are: `v = 3`, `p = 6`, and `k = 2`.

The result should be the name of the variable that contains the maximum value—the text `v`, `p`, or `k`.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# find biggest number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117251/c-sharp-find-biggest-number), [Maximum integer value find in list<int>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295112/maximum-integer-value-find-in-listint)

Comment: Just for your information, the community here responds better to questions that show evidence of your attempts to solve the problem for yourself. That will make it less likely to get downvoted and/or closed. For example, here you could have said that you tried using `Math.Max`, but it just returned the value of the variable, whereas you wanted the *name* of the variable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you just obviated every answer already posted by not clearly stating what you wanted the first time. You can extend the use of [`Enumerable.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292667.aspx) *easily* to give you what you now want:

```
string max = 
     new[] {
         Tuple.Create(v, "v"),
         Tuple.Create(p, "p"),
         Tuple.Create(k, "k")
     }.Max()
      .Item2;
```

An alternative is:

```
string max = v >= p && v >= k ? "v" : p >= v && p >= k ? "p" : "k";
```

But do you see how much less readable that is than the first version?

Comment: answer should be vor p or k not the values

Comment: @user2272260: I do not understand your comment at all.

Comment: @user2272260 do you mean the TEXT "p", "v", or "k" based on which actual variable is biggest?

Comment: @Jason I think he wants logic like `if(v is max)`. If there are duplicate highest values, there may not even be a max.

Comment: yes the text should be the answer

Comment: @user2272260 You should clarify that in your question.

Comment: @user2272260: Please see my edit. And next time, ask the right question the first time. Note that your question title says the "value" and your question body said you want to "find the gretest" (sic), not that you want to find the *name* of the variable holding the maximum value.

Comment: sorry for that. but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Gosh, maybe I'm weird or been a C++ programmer for too long, but I actually find the second example clearer and easier to understand. I don't look at the code piece-by-piece, but rather see a larger idiom at work that is fundamentally simple. The first example looks rather complex to me; I have to stop and think about what it is doing.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are very good, but for the sake of completeness, I'd like to point out that for simplicity, you can also use [`Math.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max.aspx):

```
var max = Math.Max(Math.Max(v, p), k);
```

---

**Update** given your updated question, I'd recommend this:

```
var max = v > p ? v > k ? "V" : p > k ? "P" : "K" : p > k ? "P" : "K";
```

It's rather unwieldy, but it works (`k` wins ties with `p` or `v`, `p` wins ties with `v`).

Comment: Which also probably will perform slightly better (as it doesn't create a new list and enumerarator that all needs to be GC:ed)

Answer (score 6):

```
var values = new List<int> { v, p, k };
var maxValue = values.Max();
```

*Update, re your modified question:* The variable names don't exist in the compiled IL code. Therefore you can't easily retrieve them.

But you can create a dictionary. Off the top of my head (I didn't actually try this, but it could be somewhat along these lines):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    { "V", 3 }, { "P", 6 }, { "K", 2 }
};

var max = dict.Values.Max();
var relevantKey = dict
        .Where(x => max.Equals(x.Value))
        .Select(x => x.Key)
        .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: answer should be v or p or k not the values

Answer (score 2):

Here is some hand-maded method, based on generics and Max from Enumerable:

```
public static T MaxVal<T>(params T[] items)
{
    return items == null? default(T) : items.Max();
}
```

And for integers, for example, you can call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(MaxVal(4, 8, 15, 16, 42));
```

Comment: You don't need to specify `<int>`--the type will be inferred from the arguments.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Old habits die hard. Fixed, for clarification, also it is not the answer to updated question...