# c# Get the name of variable with greatest value

Tags: c#, variables

I Have 5 stored variables, and I want to find the variable name with the largest value.

I've used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024180/determine-the-name-of-a-variable-with-the-maximum-value) as the basis for the below code. However I don't understand what it is doing and therefore cannot be sure I'm getting the correct result.

```
p.joy = .6,
p.fear = .5,
p.sadness =.4,
p.disgust =.1,
p.anger =.7,

var emotion = p.joy > p.fear ? p.joy > p.sadness ? p.joy > p.disgust ? p.joy > p.anger ? "Joy" : "Joy" : "Joy" : p.fear > p.sadness ? p.fear > p.disgust ? p.fear > p.anger ? "Fear" : "Fear" : "Fear" : "Fear" : p.sadness > p.disgust ? p.sadness > p.anger ? "Sadness" : "Sadness" : p.disgust > p.anger ? "Disgust" : "Anger"
```

I'm am hoping someone can validate, or adjust as necessary.

**use case:** I want to return the variable name with the highest value, where there is two or more variables with the same number I want to return them in this sequence.
Anger, Fear, Sadness, Disgust, Joy

Here is the larger code segment which is linq

```
  var Watson1 = from s in db.tblWatsonToneAnalyser
                join e in db.Projects on s.ProjectRef equals e.ID
                where e.Deactivate != true && e.Type == part && e.PartitNo == item
                group s by new { s.ProjectRef} into grp
                select grp.OrderByDescending(v => v.CreatedDate).AsEnumerable().Select(p => new
                {
                    ProjectRef = p.ProjectRef,    // use this to for the join
                    ReportDate = p.CreatedDate,
                    emotion = p.joy > p.fear ? p.joy > p.sadness ? p.joy > p.disgust ? p.joy > p.anger ? "Joy" : "Joy" : "Joy" :
                                        p.fear > p.sadness ? p.fear > p.disgust ? p.fear > p.anger ? "Fear" : "Fear" : "Fear" : "Fear" :
                                        p.sadness > p.disgust ? p.sadness > p.anger ? "Sadness" : "Sadness" :
                                        p.disgust > p.anger ? "Disgust" :
                                        "Anger",

                    score = p.joy > p.fear ? p.joy > p.sadness ? p.joy > p.disgust ? p.joy > p.anger ? p.joy : p.joy : p.joy :
                              p.fear > p.sadness ? p.fear > p.disgust ? p.fear > p.anger ? p.fear : p.fear : p.fear : p.fear :
                              p.sadness > p.disgust ? p.sadness > p.anger ? p.sadness : p.sadness :
                              p.disgust > p.anger ? p.disgust :
                              p.anger,                       
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Just for clarification, this is not getting you the **name** but much rather the highest value out of them. And look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to find out what the `?` operator does.

Comment: Put all in a list, and take the highest from the list. You can do that in 2 lines and use .Max(); using linq.

Comment: If you want the name you should take a look at dictionaries like stated here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024206/5985593 otherwise you're not able to get the name of the variable @ runtime I think except when you use reflection, but that would be a little to much overhead for this case I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put everything in a list of key-value tuples, sort it, and pick the highest one by value:

```
var nameMax = (new[] {
    Tuple.Create("joy", p.joy),
    Tuple.Create("fear", p.fear),
    Tuple.Create("sadness", p.sadness),
    Tuple.Create("disgust", p.disgust),
    Tuple.Create("anger", p.anger)
}).OrderByDescending(t => t.Item2).First().Item1;
```

Comment: I like this as a possible solution but get this error::                                        LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]] Create[String,Nullable`1](System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @2bitcoder This works perfectly in the context of a stand-alone query ([demo](http://ideone.com/1uJWNv)). If you are using it inside an EF query, you need to call `AsEnumerable()` before the method that calls `Tuple.Create`

Answer (score 1):

Put them into a foldable data structure in the correct order, and voilà:

```
var emotions = new[] {
    Tuple.Create(p.anger, Emotion.Anger),
    Tuple.Create(p.fear, Emotion.Fear),
    Tuple.Create(p.sadness, Emotion.Sadness),
    Tuple.Create(p.disgust, Emotion.Disgust),
    Tuple.Create(p.joy, Emotion.Joy),
};

var highestEmotions = emotions
    .MaxByAll(t => t.Item1)
    .Select(e => e.Item2);
```

After defining an enum:

```
enum Emotion {
    Anger,
    Fear,
    Sadness,
    Disgust,
    Joy,
}
```

and an extension to take a sequence and get the maximum values (preserving order) according to a certain key:

```
public static IList<T> MaxByAll<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> key) where TKey : IComparable {
    var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
    enumerator.MoveNext();

    var maxes = new List<T> { enumerator.Current };
    TKey maxKey = key(enumerator.Current);

    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        T current = enumerator.Current;
        TKey currentKey = key(current);
        int relation = currentKey.CompareTo(maxKey);

        if (relation > 0) {
            maxes.Clear();
            maxes.Add(current);
            maxKey = currentKey;
            continue;
        }

        if (relation == 0) {
            maxes.Add(current);
        }
    }

    return maxes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by creating a struct or a class -

```
 struct p
 {
    public double joy, fear, sadness, disgust, anger;
 }
```

initialize it -

```
var p = new p();
 p.joy = .6;
 p.fear = .5;
 p.sadness = .4;
 p.disgust = .1;
 p.anger = .7;
```

Get variable/field with max value -

```
 var field = p.GetType().GetFields().OrderByDescending(f=>f.GetValue(p)).First().Name;
 Console.WriteLine(field);
```

Results `anger`